# Pop fragment out of the stack. Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer that contains FragmentContainer, FragmentMain, FragmentSub.

FragmentContainer automatically adds FragmentMain using `getChildFragmentManager`.

FragmentMain has a button that replaces current fragment with FragmentSub using `getFragmentManager`.

The problem is :

**Case 1** : If I use `getFragmentManager` to automatically add FragmentMain, there is an error when I try to rotate the screen.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
```

**Case 2** : If I use `getChildFragmentManager` there is no problem during screen rotation but after that I cannot pop fragment on the backstack.

I have these method on the MainActivity that pops the fragment out of the stack but it doesn't worked.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        } else {
           logoutDialog();
        }

    }
}
```

**FragmentContainer**

```
FragmentMain fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentMain).commit();
```

**FragmentMain**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentMain).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**FragmentSub**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentSub).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

try this in your manifest file. for rotation problem

Comment: ohh...ok...then getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager().